# JMS serialization exception php

Tags: php, serialization, jmsserializerbundle

I have the following classes

```
/**
 * @Discriminator(field = "type", map = {
 *      "b":"B",
        "c":"C",
 * })
 */
abstract class A {}

class B extends A { ... }
class C extends A {
     /**
     * @var A
     * @Serializer\Type("A")
     */
      $a
}
```

now when I serialize an object of class `C`:

> The discriminator field name "type" for base-class "A" was not found
>   in input data.

Any idea what am I doing wrong here? I am using JMS serializer.

**EDIT**

I am getting this exception when I try to deserialize the serialized object.

Answer (score 1):

An abstract class can't be initialized and therefor not deserialized.
If you need your class A, you should change it to a normal class and not beeing abstract.

I had a similar problem a year ago, this is my solution: [JMS Serializer Deserialize with abstract parent class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17275117/jms-serializer-deserialize-with-abstract-parent-class)